# DropDownList as Filter for SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

im trying to add a search function to my gridview. I already successfully added two textboxes and everythings running as expected but when i tried to add a dropdownlist it somehow doesnt work and i dont quite understand why. Heres my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelSearchTitle" runat="server" Text="Search Title"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSearchTitle" MaxLength="50" runat="server" Width="16%"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelSearchArtist" runat="server" Text="Search Artist"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSearchArtist" MaxLength="50" runat="server" Width="16%"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLSearch" runat="server" Width="16%">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">select Genre</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Pop</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Rock</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Dance</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">Latin</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="18%" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click" />
    </div>
    <asp:GridView Width="80%" ID="myGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" OnRowDeleting="grv_Delete" OnRowUpdating="grv_Update">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ValidationGroup="Insert" ID="linkButtonInsert" OnClick="linkButtonInsert_Click" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxEditTitle" MaxLength="50" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEditTitle" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Title is required"
                        Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="textBoxEditTitle"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxInsertTitle" MaxLength="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsertTitle" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Title is required"
                        Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Insert" ControlToValidate="textBoxInsertTitle"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Artist" SortExpression="Artist">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEditArtist" MaxLength="50" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Artist") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEditArtist" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Artist is required"
                        Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEditArtist"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Artist") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxInsertArtist" MaxLength="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsertArtist" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Artist is required"
                        Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Insert" ControlToValidate="textBoxInsertArtist"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Genre" SortExpression="Genre">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditGenre" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Genre") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem>select Genre</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Pop</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Rock</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dance</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Latin</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEditGenre" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Genre is required"
                        Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="ddlEditGenre" InitialValue="select Genre"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Genre") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInsertGenre" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>select Genre</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Pop</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Rock</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dance</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Latin</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsertGenre" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Genre is required" InitialValue="select Genre"
                        Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Insert" ControlToValidate="ddlInsertGenre"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="LabelAlreadyExists" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="Insert" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:ValidationSummary>
    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:ValidationSummary>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBCS %>" SelectCommand="select tblSong.ID ,Title, Artist, Genre from tblSong JOIN tblArtist on ArtistId = tblArtist.ID
        JOIN tblGenre on GenreId = tblGenre.ID;"
        UpdateCommand="select tblSong.ID ,Title, Artist, Genre from tblSong JOIN tblArtist on ArtistId = tblArtist.ID JOIN tblGenre on GenreId = tblGenre.ID;"
        DeleteCommand="select tblSong.ID ,Title, Artist, Genre from tblSong JOIN tblArtist on ArtistId = tblArtist.ID JOIN tblGenre on GenreId = tblGenre.ID;"
        FilterExpression="Title LIKE '%{0}%' AND Artist LIKE '%{1}%' AND Genre LIKE '{2}'">
        <FilterParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" ControlID="TextBoxSearchTitle" DefaultValue="" Name="Title" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" ControlID="TextBoxSearchArtist" DefaultValue="" Name="Artist" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDLSearch" Type="String" Name="Genre" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </FilterParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

When i run this code the gridview is not visible. all i see are the two labels, two textboes and the dropdownlist within the second . Can anyone explain to me why?

thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBCS %>" SelectCommand="select tblSong.ID ,Title, Artist, Genre from tblSong JOIN tblArtist on ArtistId = tblArtist.ID
        JOIN tblGenre on GenreId = tblGenre.ID;"
        UpdateCommand="select tblSong.ID ,Title, Artist, Genre from tblSong JOIN tblArtist on ArtistId = tblArtist.ID JOIN tblGenre on GenreId = tblGenre.ID;"
        DeleteCommand="select tblSong.ID ,Title, Artist, Genre from tblSong JOIN tblArtist on ArtistId = tblArtist.ID JOIN tblGenre on GenreId = tblGenre.ID;"
        FilterExpression="Title LIKE '%{0}%' AND Artist LIKE '%{1}%' AND GenreId ={2}">
        <FilterParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" ControlID="TextBoxSearchTitle" DefaultValue="" Name="Title" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" ControlID="TextBoxSearchArtist" DefaultValue="" Name="Artist" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDLSearch" Type="Int16" Name="Genre" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </FilterParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

The DDLSearch filter is based on `SelectedValue`, which is using the GenreIDs {1,2,3,4} to filter, not the Genre name.  Change your `FilterExpression` to use the ID instead of name:

```
AND GenreID ='{2}'
```

And also, if GenreID is an integer in the database, then change your DDLSearch ControlParameter to use an integer data type instead of String, and change the FilterExpression to remove the single ticks so that SQL Server does not perform an implicit conversion from int to varchar when looking up the GenreID.

```
AND GenreID ={2}
```

Also note that if you plan on having a lot of data in your `tblSong` table, then you might be better off using `SelectParameters` instead. `SelectParameters` will filter on the SQL Server side before returning the results to ASP.NET (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx). `FilterExpressions`, on the other hand, will get ALL records from the SQL Server, and then cache the results and filter on the ASP.NET side.

Comment: thank you for your help. I edited my code (see above) but now i get an exception: couldnt find row [GenreId]on page load. What did i do wrong?

Comment: could this be because im looking up the genreID in my database at  the ID Column of tblGenre table and the artistName and title at tblSong table?

Comment: Actually I haven't used FilterExpression before but after reading up on them they are applied after the data is returned from SQL Server, based on a RowFilter for the GridView DataView (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bfya48(v=vs.100).aspx).  So the item you are filtering on has to be returned as a column in  your SQLDataSource.  So add GenreID to your SelectCommand in your SQLDataSource.

Comment: Also note that if you plan on having a lot of data in your tblSongs table, then you might be better off using SelectParameters instead.  SelectParameters will filter on the SQL Server side before returning the results to ASP.NET (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx).  FilterExpressions, on the other hand, will get ALL records from the SQL Server, and then cache the results and filter on the ASP.NET side.